# How to extract closed caption from a .ts file using GStreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

how to extract the closed caption from type cea608 or cea708 from a.ts into txt file  with gst-launch-1.0?
Thanks.

i tried this :
gst-launch-1.0  filesrc location= a.ts ! tsdemux ! "closedcaption/x-cea-708" ! filesink location=subtitles

but didn't work